# Flutter Horizontal scroll view inside a nested scroll view throws out of bounds error

Tags: list, flutter

I am having difficulty nesting a horizontal list view within a nested scroll view. What I really want is a group of horizontal lists one below the other within a vertical list view sort of container.

Below is part of my flutter code which returns the error:

> Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder:(context,innerBoxIsScrolled)=>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,),
            floating: true,snap: true,
            title: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),child: Text("Swahili Times", style: TextStyle(color:Color(0xffbf0000), fontFamily: "old-english",fontSize: 20),),),
            centerTitle: true,backgroundColor: Colors.white,elevation: 4.0,
          ),
        ],
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListView.separated(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  itemBuilder: (context,item)=> buildCard(item+1),
                  separatorBuilder: (context,item)=> const SizedBox(height: 12,),
                  itemCount: 9
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the list view need to be in SizedBox or in Expanded Widgets to set it's height and it will be work successfully with no errors

```
SizedBox(
height: 200,
child : ListView.separated(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
  itemBuilder: (context,item)=> buildCard(item+1),
  separatorBuilder: (context,item)=> const SizedBox(height: 12,),
  itemCount: 9
),)
```

or you can use Expanded

```
Expanded(
child : ListView.separated(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
  itemBuilder: (context,item)=> buildCard(item+1),
  separatorBuilder: (context,item)=> const SizedBox(height: 12,),
  itemCount: 9
),)
```